# I am running JAVA. When I try to create this method i get errors. The IDE told me to use an array I did and it still didnt work

Tags: java

I created the method below but it has red lines under it in netBeans. the IDE told me to use an array and that still didnt work so i went back to this.

```
  private double getPaymentAmount(double loanValue, double paymentAmount, double numOfPayments, double periodInterestRate){
     paymentAmount =  loanValue [periodInterestRate(1+periodInterestRate)^numOfPayments]/[(1+periodInterestRate)^numOfPayments-1];   
        return paymentAmount;
```

Comment: `loanValue` isn't array.  The use of `[...]` after the variable suggests you are trying to access an element from within an array, but give the out of context nature of the code snippet, it's impossible to know exactly what you are hoping to achieve

Comment: Your code doesn't make any sense. You'll need to be a lot more specific about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing Java syntax with mathematical notation. While you might try to multiply variables as `someVar(someVar2+someVar3)` that's actually a method call. Additionally, square brackets have special meaning, and `^` is XOR and not power (use `Math.pow` instead).

```
loanValue * 
    (periodInterestRate * Math.pow(1+periodInterestRate, numOfPayments)) / 
    (Math.pow(1+periodInterestRate, numOfPayments)-1);
```

The code above has been revised to be syntactically valid. I've also taken the liberty of splitting it over multiple lines to make it more readable. However, because your original code was extremely unclear, it is possible that the mathematical meaning of my expression is different from your intention. I'm assuming that you intended to write the following:

[image]

Also, you declare `paymentAmount` as a parameter, although it is *not* a parameter, but rather a return value.

```
private double getPaymentAmount(double loanValue, double numOfPayments, double periodInterestRate) {
  double paymentAmount = loanValue * 
    (periodInterestRate * Math.pow(1+periodInterestRate, numOfPayments)) / 
    (Math.pow(1+periodInterestRate, numOfPayments)-1);
  return paymentAmount;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets don't mean the same thing as they do in math.Nethier does the caret. Caret is XOR. I think this is what you want:

```
loanValue * (Math.pow(periodInterestRate(1+periodInterestRate), numOfPayments)) / (Math.pow(1+periodInterestRate, numOfPayments-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this syntax with loanValue [calculation1]/[calculation2]?:

```
paymentAmount = loanValue[periodInterestRate(1+periodInterestRate)^numOfPayments]/[(1+periodInterestRate)^numOfPayments-1];
```

This does not look like correct use of [] and if loanValue is a function maybe it should be more like:

```
paymentAmount = loanValue(periodInterestRate((1+periodInterestRate)^numOfPayments)/((1+periodInterestRate)^numOfPayments-1));
```

Or if loanValue is an array then maybe:

```
paymentAmount = loanValue[periodInterestRate(1+periodInterestRate)^numOfPayments]/((1+periodInterestRate)^numOfPayments-1);
```

But it is hard to believe that

```
periodInterestRate(1+periodInterestRate)
```

would match an array index or even a hash key.

Then maybe loanValue is just a number, as some others have suggested.

Please clarify: What is the type of loanValue?

Thanks